# Binning time series data and removing multiples within bin

Tags: sql, time, greatest-n-per-group, reduction, binning

2 columns in Sql Server Mgmt studio out of many are ID and DateTime. There are repetitions of some rows, and some the datetime values have varying frequencies...i.e, for 1 ID there may be 3 repeated datetime values , and then the next two for that ID may be 2 minutes later, then another 2 just 20 seconds later.

I want to grab just one row for each 5 minute bin for each ID, or at least make sure each ID's entries are at a minimum 5 minutes apart. Its around 400 million rows and 17 columns, and unfortunately right now they are all varchar(50). I dont know much about DB management, but do know when I tried to even just change the data type on my local machine DB it gobbled up all my remaining disk space real quick. Any suggestions would be very welcomed. Thanks

Comment: What database do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for SQL Server.

To create 5 minute groups you can use `DATEDIFF(mi, 0, DateTime) / 12`.

After that you just need to take first record in each combination of ID and 5-minute interval like this:

```
WITH binned_data AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (
        PARTITION BY ID, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, DateTime) / 12 
        order by DateTime
    ) AS RowNo 
    FROM my_data
)
SELECT * FROM binned_data WHERE RowNo = 1
```